# Can I use el as div identification for other libraries?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

I'm using backbone.js and iScroll. As part of the render process I need to create a new instance of iScroll and I'm suppose to pass it a div `id`.

```
new_iScroll = new iScroll 'divID'
```

When rendering things with backbone I love not having to uniquely `id` every parent div to be able to target it. Could I do something similar in this case? Is there any way I could pass in `this.el`? If not what is the next best way to handle this kind of `id`ing in the context of backbone?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [line 58](https://github.com/cubiq/iscroll/blob/master/src/iscroll.js#L58) in iscroll.js: yes, you can pass in a regular DOM element as well as an ID